# OData API for a Azure search index not returning metadata

Tags: odata, azure-cognitive-search

We are having issue with OData API for an Azure search index that it is not returning metadata. We are able to perform OData based queries but not able to access metadata

Our expectation was that Odata end point

> https://*search-service-name*.search.windows.net/indexes/*index-name*?api-version=2019-05-06&api-key=XXXXXXXXXXX&odata.metadata=full

should return the metadata.
Other end points we have tried

> https://*search-service-name*.search.windows.net/indexes('*index-name*')/$metadata?api-version=2019-05-06&api-key=XXXXXXXX&odata.metadata=full

If we use the api-key set up for querying, we get error
{
  "error": {
    "code": "",
    "message": "Authorization failed."
  }
}

Using Admin key as api-key, error returned is 
{
  "Message": "The given API key is not permitted in the URI query string."
}

Has anyone else been able to get full OData API working with Azure search Index?

Thanks

Comment: I'm curious -- Why do you need full OData metadata?

Comment: We are currently looking to see if odata.metadata=minimal will be enough to configure Search Index documents as External Objects in SF.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm curious to learn more about this scenario. Depending on your usage pattern, pulling data from Azure Search directly via OData may or may not be a good idea. If you're interested in continuing this conversation, feel free to email me at bruce dot johnston at microsoft.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `odata.metadata=full` and `api-key` need to be passed as HTTP headers, not query-string parameters. `api-key` is its own header, while `odata.metadata=full` is a parameter that should be part of the `Accept` header, like this: `application/json;odata.metadata=full`.

That said, unless you're trying to use Azure Search with an OData-enabled client for which you can't change the code, you shouldn't need the full OData metadata. At most you'd need `odata.metadata=minimal` to include type annotations for parts of the REST API that use inheritance (for example, when configuring analyzers, skills, or change/deletion detection policies for indexers).

Comment: Thank you. We were able to get it working with HTTP headers.

We are using the API with OData enabled client (SF.com External Data Object ~ Virtual Entity inside SF). We are analyzing if odata.metadata=minimal is sufficient for connector.

Comment: @BruceJohnston You solved my issue. My upvote +1.  I had a similar issue when working on this [Create an Azure Cognitive Search index using REST APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-get-started-rest). Passing the api-key in the headers resolved the issue. Before I was passing it in the URL.